# Как сделать письмо с меткой о регистрации?

Tags: html, email, phpmailer

Всем привет, сделал небольшой сайт с возможностью зарегистрироваться и отправить заявку на консультацию, через phpMailer организовал отправку email, но не могу найти информуцию о том, как сделать моё письмо со значком, например при подтверждении регистрации чтобы был ключик (и не в теме письма, а рядом с письмом, в теме письма воткнуть эмоджи не составляет труда), а например при покупке отрисовывалась бы тележка и т.д,как вообще такие значки к письму добавлять? Я предполагаю, что дело возможно в каком то заголовке, но найти не получилось, подскажите как это сделать или где почитать?

Answer (score 1):

Это делается с помощью html писем. Вы должны сверстать его и отправить с пометкой, что это html письмо, тогда почта поймёт это и покажет всё что вы сверстали

Comment: Ну вот как это указыать в шаблоне письма? Например приходит письмо мне на почту из банка, оно помечено "финансы", а рядом с темой письма значок российского рубля, та же песня с чеками, которые идут от магазина, когда приходит письмо подтверждения регистрации рядом значок ключика, все остальные письма от этого отправителя без этих значков, как их сделать? Может быть есть категории писем?